# Raising INotifyPropertyChanged for all members of a class/struct?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

So I've got a project set up like this

```
Class Dataclass
{
  var data
  var data;
  var data;
 }

class DataViewModel
{
   private Dataclass thing;

   public string thingPropertyName = "thing";
   public Dataclass Thing
   {
     get { return thing; }
     set { thing = value; RaisedPropertyChanged(thingPropertyName);}
   }
 }
```

So here is my issue:  If I bind to a subproperty via the Thing field in my ModelView class, the bindings do not update if any of the members of the class change, only if the entire object changed, as what I believe is intentional.

How can I get around this, so that if I do anything to the members of the contained Dataclass, my bindings update properly?

The first thing I'd looked at was was wrapping every element of the subclass into a property of the parent class, like so:

```
public var Data
{
   get { return thing.Data; }
   set { thing.Data = value; RaisePropertyChanged(DataProperyName);}
}
```

This works, however I still have an issue when the subclass object is initialized.  The only solution I can see is to manually call RaisedPropertyName() for each element when the class is initialized.  This seems like a less than optimal way to do it.  I was hoping that there would be a better approach.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice avatar (reminds me someone else's)  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are binding to a property of DataClass, and want the binding to be refreshed (which is ultimately the goal of using bindings), then it means your DataClass must implement INotifyPropertyChanged (whose purpose is exactly that).

If you don't want DataClass to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, for "layers" reasons (e.g.: you don't want your Data classes to implement concerns related to Views), then your DataViewModel must act as a pass-through for each property that you need. This is the second solution that you propose.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, calling `RaisePropertyChanged(null)` (assuming that this ultimately invokes a call to the appropriate INotifyPropertyChanged event delegate with null as the property name parameter in the args structure) will tell all bound listeners to refresh.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware that the INotifyPropertyChanged would function like this.

Comment: @Brandorf, it's not guaranteed, as not all listeners will properly interpret the null.  It definitely works with DependencyProperty bindings in a WPF context, but other clients may subscribe to NotifyPropertyChanged and not handle the null correctly.